# Partition pairs of numbers such that no partition contain two pairs with the same number.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

**Problem**

Integers $1, 2, 3, ..., n$ can form $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of numbers.

I want to partition these pairs of numbers such that:

1. The number of partition is as low as possible
2. None of the partitions contains two pairs that share the same number.

How to do that?

**Example**

For n = 5, the following partition satisfies requirement 2:

- A: (1, 2), (3, 4)
- B: (2, 3), (4, 5)
- C: (1, 3), (2, 4)
- D: (3, 5)
- E: (1, 4), (2, 5)
- F: (1, 5)

Comment: Equivalently, on a n-complete graph, assign the edges to minimal number of sets such that no set contains edges that share a vertex. Does this kind of problem have a name?

Comment: Your example is missing $(2,3)$ and $(4,5)$?

Comment: @DanielMathias you are right. Fixed.

Comment: 12/34,13/45,14/25,15/23,24/35 is minimal for n=5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [edge coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) of the complete graph $K_n$. For each color, the edges of that color will form one part of the partition.

Each color can only be used on $\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ edges. So we need at least $\binom n2/\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ colors: this is $n-1$ when $n$ is even, and $n$ when $n$ is odd.

This is in fact possible, and is explained in Wikipedia's article on [Baranyai's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai%27s_theorem) (a more general statement). The construction has a nice geometric description. Put $n-1$ vertices equally spaced in a circle and $1$ vertex at the center. For each color, pick one edge out of the central vertex, and all the edges perpendicular to that edge. Here is an image of the $n=8$ case (taken from the Wikipedia article):

[image: image from the above Wikipedia article]

For odd $n$, just use the coloring of $K_{n+1}$ obtained with this approach, and ignore edges out of vertex $n+1$.

An alternative formulation of the odd-$n$ solution is to partition pairs $\{x,y\}$ into $n$ classes based on $x+y \bmod n$. (Then $\{x,y\}$ and $\{x,z\}$ cannot be in the same class for $y \ne z$.)